# XPages dataTable control, compute visible

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I am trying to learn how to do a computed visible property on a dataTable  to hide an field/ row if status is enabled or disabled.

below code is what i have used but keep getting error

```
var userName=rowData.getColumnValue("userName")
var status:NotesView = database.getView("(UserProfile)");
var doc:NotesDocument = status.getDocumentByKey(userName);
var active = doc.getItemValueString("Status")
if(active == "Enabled") {
    return true
}else{
return false
}
```

Comment: What error? and what does the XPages log file say?

Comment: i keep geting  line=4, col=18: 'doc' is null

Comment: print(userName) to check if name is in first sorted column in view "(UserProfile)". It has to be the same spelling...

Comment: Is *first sorted* column in view the column with the user names?

Comment: The view bind to the dataTable is diffrent from the view of the status but the value of the first sorted column in the view (UserProfile) is the same as the value  bind to the datatable but not in the userName first column

Comment: I meant: is the *first sorted* column in view **"(UserProfile)"** the user names column? There have to be listed all user names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70593/discussion-between-simon-peter-and-knut-herrmann).

Comment: That's an awful lot of document lookups. There's room for tuning. Step1 would be to add the status field to the user profile view and do a ```@dblookup``` instead. Step2 would be some caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code into a try-catch-block as you want the part only be visible if user is in view "(UserProfile)" and has a certain status:

```
try {
    var userName=rowData.getColumnValue("userName")
    var status:NotesView = database.getView("(UserProfile)");
    var doc:NotesDocument = status.getDocumentByKey(userName);
    var active = doc.getItemValueString("Status")
    if(active == "Enabled") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this failing on page load or during a partial refresh? If the latter, you could be hitting the problem that I mention here http://www.intec.co.uk/dataviews-and-nested-repeats/. A partial refresh is a number of server-side phases, during which the server-side map of the page is retrieved, values from the browser applied, and the contents of the Data Table recalculated. During the early phases, the variable `rowData` will be null, which means `doc` will also be null.

Using a logging mechanism like [XPages OpenLog Logger](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20OpenLog%20Logger) will capture the stack trace which will include the phase it's failing in.

Use `view.isRenderingPhase()` to only run the code in the Render Response phase (the phase that writes HTML back to the browser). It will avoid phase-specific issues and also optimise the performance. If it's rendered property, that's the only phase you need to compute the value in ;-)

Comment: yes the error come  during partial refresh, am new to XPages so am not sure where to insert or use the `view.isRenderingPhase()` can you please trow more light on that, thanks

Comment: if (view.isRenderingPhase()) {
  // run code
} else {
  return false;
}

That will still allow error handling with try / catch